# WPF bind a button from Window template to ViewModel's command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I have a window that looks like this

[image]

As You can see there's a **button** on the '**window bar**' itself, and I want to bind button command to the ViewModel's command

Here's how the visual tree looks like

[image]

I've tried various combinatios using RelativeSource but can't find a way for this to work..

Any kind of help or ideas would be appreciated

Code for the window itself..

```
<dx:DXWindow x:Class="Chronos.WindowsApp.Windows.TimersCollectionWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:themes="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core/themekeys"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Title="Timers" 
             ShowInTaskbar = "False" 
             ShowIcon="True" Icon="/Chronos.UserControls;component/Images/TimersWindowIconW.png"
             d:DesignHeight="80" d:DesignWidth="80"
             >

    <dx:DXWindow.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="{themes:FloatingContainerThemeKey ThemeName=Mishcon, ResourceKey=FloatingContainerDragWidgetTemplate, IsThemeIndependent=True}" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Border Height="40" Background="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Transparent"
                            Width="70"
                            Height="35"
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=dx:DXWindow}, Path=RootControl.DataContext.NewTimmerCommand}"
                            >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image Source="{dx:DXImage Image=Add_32x32.png}" Width="24" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Add" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </dx:DXWindow.Resources>
</dx:DXWindow>
```

The error I'm getting is :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'RootControl' property not found on 'object' ''TimersCollectionWindow'
>   (Name='')'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=RootControl.DataContext.NewTimmerCommand;
>   DataItem='TimersCollectionWindow' (Name=''); target element is
>   'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: Have you tried `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=dx:DXWindow}, Path=DataContext.NewTimmerCommand}"`?

Comment: Could you show XAML of the window (simplified)?

Comment: @Michal - how would I do that ?

Comment: @Mary - I simply want to see how you declared UI in XAML. It usually helps a lot.

Comment: What is the source of DataContext for RootControl?

Comment: @StepUp - yes ouf course. doest work.. and doest show any err

Comment: @MichałKomorowski - it's a ViewModel - TimerCollectionViewModel.. You can see in the screenShot - the dataContext Tab is selected for the RootControl

Comment: @Marty - I meant how did you set DataContext for RootControl? Is it inherited, populated in code behind...?

Comment: In short - a documentManager services create's a window, then creates a view, then creates a viewModel, assigns it to the view, and then places the View inside of the window

Comment: Try to write `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=x:Type dx:DXWindow}, Path=DataContext.NewTimmerCommand}` or `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.NewTimmerCommand}`

Comment: @StepUp - It might not be enough. From what I understand DataContext property for a window is not populated.

Comment: @Marty - Could you try to set DataContext for a window and use a solution given by @StepUp?

Comment: Can I set the same object to be the dataContext for 2 things ? I'll try looking into that.. I was kinda hoping to solve this with some clever "binding" expression..

Comment: @Marty - If you set DataContext at the window level it should be inherited by controls within this window.

Comment: I know.. but the DocumentManagerService is still gonna be setting it directly on the view.. else I have to rewrite, override how the document manager services bahaves, and how it creates views'

Comment: @MichałKomorowski but from the error we can see that the DC is already presented. Isn't it?

Comment: @Ilan - My understanding is that it is present but not for a button. It is why I suggested to set DataContext at the window level so that the button will "inherit" it.

Comment: #@MichałKomorowski We can see from the binding error that ''RootControl' property not found on 'object' ''TimersCollectionWindow''' that means the DataContext is presented but RootControl property couldn't be foun there.

Comment: @MichałKomorowski - if You want answer the question with a suggestion to set the dataContext of the window. Appearently - WPF is fine with the thing, that the same object is set as DataContext in multiple place`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from your Binding Expression error the object on witch it tries to find your path is TimersCollectionWindow, if your command exist inside this class 
then I think you should do a direct binding like that:

**Button xaml code**

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Transparent"
                        Width="70"
                        Height="35"
                        Command="{Binding NewTimmerCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode = TwoWay}">
```

**VM command declaration**

```
    public ICommand NewTimmerCommand
    {
        get { return _newTimmerCommand; }
        set
        {
            _newTimmerCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NewTimmerCommand");
        }
    }
```

In case when your command is into a data context of an object that is using a defined ContentTemplate , then just do the next. Since the target type for your ContentTemplate is a Thumb, it will be definitely created on time when the ContentTemplate will be in use, the Thumb will inherit its DataContext from its parent, thus you can rely your binding to a Thumb and get your command from its (and its parent) data context.

**XAML button code**

```
 <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Transparent"
                        Width="70"
                        Height="35"
                        Command="{Binding 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Thumb}}, 
                    Path=DataContext.NewTimmerCommand}">
```

**Update**

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Transparent"
                        Width="70"
                        Height="35"
                        Command="{Binding 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type the_type_of_RootControl}}, 
                    Path=DataContext.NewTimmerCommand}">
```

Regards.

Comment: Yeah, that's the point.. that the command does not exist in the 'TimerWindow'  class.. the command exists in 'TimersCollectionViewModel' - which is assigned as a dataContext to the 'RootControl' element in the tree

Comment: @Marty where is the RootControl defined?

Comment: @Marty Is only the RootControl using this DataTemplate?

Comment: the 'RootControl' - is my actual View (from MVVM) which has a viewModel attached to it. Once there, then 'documentManagerService' kick in, and takes care of placing the view into a 'specified' window, or panel or frame or tab.

Comment: specifying thumb didn't help either. Error : System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'NewTimmerCommand' property not found on 'object' ''BackgroundPanel' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.NewTimmerCommand; DataItem='Thumb' (Name='PART_DragWidget'); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: @Marty what is the type of that view? please try to relate your binding to the type of RootControl. see the update.

Comment: The Type of the view is - TimerCollectionNewView, Viewmodel is TimerCollectionViewModel

Comment: I think I have an idea why that doesn't work.. cause there was a case when binding didn't show any errors but still did not work.. I'm guessing - is that the 'Thumb' is stealing mouse clicks and the button.command never gets executed.. Will update..